# Space sailor helps build a boat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Science Fiction. Short Story. Mid 1990s. Paperback

A retired enlisted Space Navy veteran helps younger civilians build an armed surface vessel boat (think a wet navy patrol boat or PT boat) to escape thier area, I think because of encroaching radiation. They need a armed boat to fight their way down river past bandits. The setting was some what post apocolyptic.

The twist at the end of the story was that the Veteran knew nothing about wet navy boats other then what he had read in books, after all he was in the space navy not a surface wet navy. But did such a masterful job building the boat and acting as captian no one was the wiser. Does not take place on earth. The veteran dies in at the end of the story saving the rest of the crew.

There was an epitaph at the end of the story that has stuck in my head for years. That the survivors engrave on the vets tombstone: "Any man can make a rate, but only God makes Boswains Mates"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Boatswain* by Alan Brown in War World IV: Invasion, one of the spinoff of the Falkenberg books by Pournelle, which are a spinoff of *The Mote in God's Eye* by Niven and Pournelle.

Comment: This was going to be my answer. A powerboat moored to a raft with structures on it. The vessel isn't armed as such though they have a variety of small arms.